# Filter List collection based on property of child list contains a name

Tags: c#, linq

I want to have LinQ query to filter list collection , when element of child list contains a name . Here child list of parent should be meet the contains criteria  and those child list only included with parent list.

Example:

```
public class Student
{
    int Id;
    List<subject> SubjectList;
    string Name;
}

public class Subject
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}

List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
```

Here I want a LINQ query to filter only StudentList of SubjectList, which subject name should be contains "maths" and result must be studentlist with subjectlist, which is only contains maths.

Comment: Your code won´t even compile as you don´t assign any data-types to your members.

Comment: Here i have put the code for your example. I want the linq query for the same scenaria...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where is the problem?

```
var mathStudents = StudentList.Where(x => x.SubjectList.Any(y => y.Name == "maths"));
```

Returns all the elements from `StudentList` that have at least one `Subject` in their `SubjectList` whose `Name` is `maths`.

If you want only the maths-courses of every student you may use this:

```
var mathCourses = mathStudents.Select(x => new 
{ 
    x.Student, 
    Math = x.SubjectList.Where(y => y.Name == "maths") 
});
```

Comment: Hi Him, I have tried this. but here the subjectlist shows all subjects incase of any one subject name meet the condition. But i want student list only which subject list name should be "math".exclude other subject model in the subject list except "math"

Comment: So you want those students having a maths-course. For all of those you want only the maths-course itself in the `SubjectList`.property of every `Student`?

Comment: Hi, Yes. exactly need solution for it.