# Get all objects that have an object that matches a string

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a database of Members. Members have a list of phone numbers. I'm trying to get all the members who have the specified phone number.

```
public class Member {
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    ...
}

...

private IMongoCollection<Member> _members;

...
private List<Member> GetMembers(string phone) {
    List<Member> list = _members.Find(
        member => member.Phones.First(
        p=>p.Number == phone).Number.Equals(phone)).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

`GetMembers` returns an empty list (Yes, the string `phone`  matches a member in the database). How can I get a list of member's who have the given phone number?

IMongoCollection Doc:
http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1.htm

Comment: Assuming `_members` is an EF DB Context, `Find()` searches by primary key. I think you just what to use `Where()`.

Comment: @Crowcoder That assumption is wrong, The `DbSet<T>.Find` method does not allow you to pass in a `Func`

Comment: While [Filter List collection based on property of child list contains a name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40479734/3744182) isn't strictly a duplicate, the use of `Any()` inside the Lambda method would seem to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) to retrieve members that match that [`.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2) of their phones have the desired number:

```
var result = _members.Where(m => m.Phones.Any(p => p.Number == phone));
```

---

Correction - as @bwoogie pointed out the `IMongoCollection` does not have a `Where` function but instead [`Find`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindAsync__1.htm):

```
var result = _members.Find(m => m.Phones.Any(p => p.Number == phone));
```

Comment: `IMongoCollection` doesn't have `Where`

Comment: using `var list = _members.Find(m => m.Phones.Any(p => p.Number == phone)).ToList();` works though.